# Bash tool to get nth line from a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

Is there a "canonical" way of doing that? I've been using `head -n | tail -1` which does the trick, but I've been wondering if there's a Bash tool that specifically extracts a line (or a range of lines) from a file.

By "canonical" I mean a program whose main function is doing that.

Comment: The "Unix way" is to chain tools that do their respective job well. So I think you already found a very suitable method. Other methods include `awk` and `sed` and I'm sure someone can come up with a Perl one-liner or so as well ;)

Comment: The double-command suggests that the `head | tail` solution is sub-optimal. Other more nearly optimal solutions have been suggested.

Comment: Have you ran any benchmarks on which solution is the fastest for an average case?

Comment: Benchmarks (for a range) at [cat line X to line Y on a huge file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47407/11750) on [Unix.SE]. (cc @Marcin, in case you're still wondering after two+ years)

Comment: The `head  | tail` solution does not work, if you query a line that does not exist in the input: it will print the last line.

Comment: A solution that is certainly not faster than any of the dedicated tools mentioned in existing answers (thus why I'm making it a comment) but that may be useful for very tight embedded systems that may have few or no text processing tools is a loop that only needs POSIX-compatible shell built-ins (NUM is the desired line): `NUM=1000; while read X; do test "$NUM" -eq "0" && echo "$X" && break; NUM=$((NUM - 1)); done < filename`

Comment: Made a script `usage: nth line [file]`, if file is omitted looks at stdin : https://github.com/BuonOmo/dotfiles/blob/main/.zsh/custom/functions/nth

Comment: `head -n$NN file | tail -1` may take more time, but this NIX logic can also solve the reverse problem: `tail -n$NN file | head -1` gives you the NN-th line counting from the back of the file, while using `sed` or `awk` needs some arithmetics, too.

Answer (score 1121, accepted):

`head` and pipe with `tail` will be slow for a huge file. I would suggest `sed` like this:

```
sed 'NUMq;d' file
```

Where `NUM` is the number of the line you want to print; so, for example, `sed '10q;d' file` to print the 10th line of `file`.

Explanation:

`NUMq` will quit immediately when the line number is `NUM`.

`d` will delete the line instead of printing it; this is inhibited on the last line because the `q` causes the rest of the script to be skipped when quitting.

If you have `NUM` in a variable, you will want to use double quotes instead of single:

```
sed "${NUM}q;d" file
```

Comment: For those wondering, this solution seems about 6 to 9 times faster than the `sed -n 'NUMp'` and `sed 'NUM!d'` solutions proposed below.

Comment: I think `tail -n+NUM file | head -n1` is likely to be just as fast or faster. At least, it was (significantly) faster on my system when I tried it with NUM being 250000 on a file with half a million lines. YMMV, but I don't really see why it would.

Comment: @rici and you can easily choose how many lines past that point by changing `head -n1` to `head -nNUM2`, you should make this it's own answer

Comment: How do you use this with a range of lines from line n to m?

Comment: For range better use `sed -n '2,5{p;5q;}' file`

Comment: @anubhava isn't `sed -n '2,5p' file` just the same?

Comment: no it is not. Without `q` it will process full file

Comment: This is a good solution, but if you want to assign the output of the sed command to a variable using command substitution it will not work if the returned line contains a double asterisk.  In the case where `sed "4q;d" file4` returns `** banana` , `foo=$(sed "4q;d" file4)` will assign the value `file1 file2 file3 file4 banana` to the variable `foo` (file1 - file4 being the directory contents).

Comment: @Fiddlestiques: Don't forget quoting to make it `foo="$(sed "4q;d" file4)"`

Comment: @anubhava - thanks - got it now - echo "$foo" rather than echo $foo

Comment: Made a script from this solution `usage: nth line [file]`, if file is omitted looks at stdin : https://github.com/BuonOmo/dotfiles/blob/main/.zsh/custom/functions/nth

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why `d` is necessary? Why do you need to "delete" anything at all in this case?

Comment: @anubhava I read the answer, but I created a comment because I did not understand the explanation. Why even include the "delete" command if the end result is that the command is inhibited by the "quit" command? Why not just have "NUMq"? Why are we deleting instead of printing for the original poster's question?

Comment: Try running `sed "${NUM}q" file` and you will understand better why `;d` is also needed

Comment: What happens if the file is too short and has no such line?

Comment: @LeeMeador: Output will be nothing for that case.

Answer (score 416):

```
sed -n '2p' < file.txt
```

will print 2nd line

```
sed -n '2011p' < file.txt
```

2011th line

```
sed -n '10,33p' < file.txt
```

line 10 up to line 33

```
sed -n '1p;3p' < file.txt
```

1st and 3th line

and so on...

For adding lines with sed, you can check this:

[sed: insert a line in a certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15555781/#16246806)

Comment: Why is the '<' necessary in this case? Wouldn't I achieve the same output without it?

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa the `<` in this case is not necessary. Simply, it is my preference using redirects, because me often used redirects like `sed -n '100p' < <(some_command)` - so, universal syntax :). It is NOT less effective, because redirection are done with shell when forking itself, so... it is only a preference... (and yes, it is one character longer) :)

Comment: @jm666 Actually it's 2 characters longer since you would normally put the '<' as well as an extra space ' ' after < as oppposed to just one space if you hadn't used the < :)

Comment: @rasen58 the space is an character too? :) /okay, just kidding - youre right/ :)

Comment: This is about 5 times slower than the tail / head combination when reading a file with 50M rows

Comment: @duhaime of course, if someone needs to do optimizations. But IMHO for the "common" problems it is ok and the difference is unnoticeable. Also, the `head`/`tail` doesn't solves the `sed -n '1p;3p'` scenario - aka print more non-adjacent rows...

Comment: Amen! Just wanted to create a note for fools like me who have to do line lookups billions of times for some task...

Comment: @duhaime of course - the note is correct and needed. :)

Answer (score 132):

I have a unique situation where I can benchmark the solutions proposed on this page, and so I'm writing this answer as a consolidation of the proposed solutions with included run times for each.

**Set Up**

I have a 3.261 gigabyte ASCII text data file with one key-value pair per row. The file contains 3,339,550,320 rows in total and defies opening in any editor I have tried, including my go-to Vim. I need to subset this file in order to investigate some of the values that I've discovered only start around row ~500,000,000.

Because the file has so many rows:

- I need to extract only a subset of the rows to do anything useful with the data.
- Reading through every row leading up to the values I care about is going to take a long time.
- If the solution reads past the rows I care about and continues reading the rest of the file it will waste time reading almost 3 billion irrelevant rows and take 6x longer than necessary.

My best-case-scenario is a solution that extracts only a single line from the file without reading any of the other rows in the file, but I can't think of how I would accomplish this in Bash.

For the purposes of my sanity I'm not going to be trying to read the full 500,000,000 lines I'd need for my own problem. Instead I'll be trying to extract row 50,000,000 out of 3,339,550,320 (which means reading the full file will take 60x longer than necessary).

I will be using the `time` built-in to benchmark each command.

**Baseline**

First let's see how the `head` `tail` solution:

```
$ time head -50000000 myfile.ascii | tail -1
pgm_icnt = 0

real    1m15.321s
```

The baseline for row 50 million is 00:01:15.321, if I'd gone straight for row 500 million it'd probably be ~12.5 minutes.

**cut**

I'm dubious of this one, but it's worth a shot:

```
$ time cut -f50000000 -d$'\n' myfile.ascii
pgm_icnt = 0

real    5m12.156s
```

This one took 00:05:12.156 to run, which is much slower than the baseline! I'm not sure whether it read through the entire file or just up to line 50 million before stopping, but regardless this doesn't seem like a viable solution to the problem.

**AWK**

I only ran the solution with the `exit` because I wasn't going to wait for the full file to run:

```
$ time awk 'NR == 50000000 {print; exit}' myfile.ascii
pgm_icnt = 0

real    1m16.583s
```

This code ran in 00:01:16.583, which is only ~1 second slower, but still not an improvement on the baseline. At this rate if the exit command had been excluded it would have probably taken around ~76 minutes to read the entire file!

**Perl**

I ran the existing Perl solution as well:

```
$ time perl -wnl -e '$.== 50000000 && print && exit;' myfile.ascii
pgm_icnt = 0

real    1m13.146s
```

This code ran in 00:01:13.146, which is ~2 seconds faster than the baseline. If I'd run it on the full 500,000,000 it would probably take ~12 minutes.

**sed**

The top answer on the board, here's my result:

```
$ time sed "50000000q;d" myfile.ascii
pgm_icnt = 0

real    1m12.705s
```

This code ran in 00:01:12.705, which is 3 seconds faster than the baseline, and ~0.4 seconds faster than Perl. If I'd run it on the full 500,000,000 rows it would have probably taken ~12 minutes.

**mapfile**

I have bash 3.1 and therefore cannot test the mapfile solution.

**Conclusion**

It looks like, for the most part, it's difficult to improve upon the `head` `tail` solution. At best the `sed` solution provides a ~3% increase in efficiency.

(percentages calculated with the formula `% = (runtime/baseline - 1) * 100`)

**Row 50,000,000**

1. 00:01:12.705 (-00:00:02.616 = -3.47%) `sed`
2. 00:01:13.146 (-00:00:02.175 = -2.89%) `perl`
3. 00:01:15.321 (+00:00:00.000 = +0.00%) `head|tail`
4. 00:01:16.583 (+00:00:01.262 = +1.68%) `awk`
5. 00:05:12.156 (+00:03:56.835 = +314.43%) `cut`

**Row 500,000,000**

1. 00:12:07.050 (-00:00:26.160) `sed`
2. 00:12:11.460 (-00:00:21.750) `perl`
3. 00:12:33.210 (+00:00:00.000) `head|tail`
4. 00:12:45.830 (+00:00:12.620) `awk`
5. 00:52:01.560 (+00:40:31.650) `cut`

**Row 3,338,559,320**

1. 01:20:54.599 (-00:03:05.327) `sed`
2. 01:21:24.045 (-00:02:25.227) `perl`
3. 01:23:49.273 (+00:00:00.000) `head|tail`
4. 01:25:13.548 (+00:02:35.735) `awk`
5. 05:47:23.026 (+04:24:26.246) `cut`

Comment: I wonder how long just cat'ting the entire file into /dev/null would take. (What if this was only a hard disk benchmark?)

Comment: I feel a perverse urge to bow at your ownership of a 3+ gig text file dictionary.  Whatever the rationale, this so embraces textuality :)

Comment: The overhead of running two processes with `head` + `tail` will be negligible for a single file, but starts to show when you do this on many files.

Answer (score 65):

With `awk` it is pretty fast:

```
awk 'NR == num_line' file
```

When this is true, the default behaviour of `awk` is performed: `{print $0}`.

---

#### Alternative versions

If your file happens to be huge, you'd better `exit` after reading the required line. This way you save CPU time <sup>See time comparison at the end of the answer</sup>.

```
awk 'NR == num_line {print; exit}' file
```

If you want to give the line number from a bash variable you can use:

```
awk 'NR == n' n=$num file
awk -v n=$num 'NR == n' file   # equivalent
```

---

See how much time is saved by using `exit`, specially if the line happens to be in the first part of the file:

```
# Let's create a 10M lines file
for ((i=0; i<100000; i++)); do echo "bla bla"; done > 100Klines
for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do cat 100Klines; done > 10Mlines

$ time awk 'NR == 1234567 {print}' 10Mlines
bla bla

real    0m1.303s
user    0m1.246s
sys 0m0.042s
$ time awk 'NR == 1234567 {print; exit}' 10Mlines
bla bla

real    0m0.198s
user    0m0.178s
sys 0m0.013s
```

So the difference is 0.198s vs 1.303s, around 6x times faster.

Comment: This method is always going to be slower because awk attempts to do field splitting. The overhead of field splitting can be reduced by `awk 'BEGIN{FS=RS}(NR == num_line) {print; exit}' file`

Comment: The real power of awk in this method comes forth when you want to concatenate line n1 of file1, n2 of file2, n3 or file3 ... `awk 'FNR==n' n=10 file1 n=30 file2 n=60 file3`. With GNU awk this can be sped up using `awk 'FNR==n{print;nextfile}' n=10 file1 n=30 file2 n=60 file3` .

Comment: @kvantour indeed, GNU awk's nextfile is great for such things. How come `FS=RS` avoids field splitting?

Comment: `FS=RS` does not avoid field splitting, but it only parses the $0 ones and only assigns one field because there is no `RS` in `$0`

Comment: @kvantour I've been doing some tests with `FS=RS` and did not see difference on the timings. What about me asking a question about it so you can expand? Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui : there's absolutely ***nothing*** `gnu`-unique about `nextfile` - i have `gawk` `mawk-1`  `mawk-2` and even `macos nawk` on my machine, and all 4 handle the `nextfile` command just fine

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto oh, I thought it was. Checking [`nextfile` statement in GNU Awk user guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) I see: _NOTE: For many years, nextfile was a common extension. In September 2012, it was accepted for inclusion into the POSIX standard._, so you are right. It also adds _The current version of BWK awk and mawk also support nextfile. However, they don’t allow the nextfile statement inside function bodies_.

Comment: @fedorqui : that's true indeed, although … ever since i first started using awk 5 years ago, i haven't even encountered scenarios in my own use case where i needed to use nextfile at all. if one really needs to use it in a function i suppose they can always use `gawk`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto well, in my case [I have found it useful on some scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1983854+nextfile)...

Comment: @fedorqui i'm happy for you

Answer (score 48):

According to my tests, in terms of performance and readability my recommendation is:

`tail -n+N | head -1`

`N` is the line number that you want. For example, `tail -n+7 input.txt | head -1` will print the 7th line of the file.

`tail -n+N` will print everything starting from line `N`, and `head -1` will make it stop after one line.

---

The alternative `head -N | tail -1` is perhaps slightly more readable. For example, this will print the 7th line:

`head -7 input.txt | tail -1`

When it comes to performance, there is not much difference for smaller sizes, but it will be outperformed by the `tail | head` (from above) when the files become huge.

The top-voted `sed 'NUMq;d'` is interesting to know, but I would argue that it will be understood by fewer people out of the box than the head/tail solution and it is also slower than tail/head.

In my tests, both tails/heads versions outperformed `sed 'NUMq;d'` consistently. That is in line with the other benchmarks that were posted. It is hard to find a case where tails/heads was really bad. It is also not surprising, as these are operations that you would expect to be heavily optimized in a modern Unix system.

To get an idea about the performance differences, these are the number that I get for a huge file (9.3G):

- `tail -n+N | head -1`: 3.7 sec
- `head -N | tail -1`: 4.6 sec
- `sed Nq;d`: 18.8 sec

Results may differ, but the performance `head | tail` and `tail | head` is, in general, comparable for smaller inputs, and `sed` is always slower by a significant factor (around 5x or so).

To reproduce my benchmark, you can try the following, but be warned that it will create a 9.3G file in the current working directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
readonly file=tmp-input.txt
readonly size=1000000000
readonly pos=500000000
readonly retries=3

seq 1 $size > $file
echo "*** head -N | tail -1 ***"
for i in $(seq 1 $retries) ; do
    time head "-$pos" $file | tail -1
done
echo "-------------------------"
echo
echo "*** tail -n+N | head -1 ***"
echo

seq 1 $size > $file
ls -alhg $file
for i in $(seq 1 $retries) ; do
    time tail -n+$pos $file | head -1
done
echo "-------------------------"
echo
echo "*** sed Nq;d ***"
echo

seq 1 $size > $file
ls -alhg $file
for i in $(seq 1 $retries) ; do
    time sed $pos'q;d' $file
done
/bin/rm $file
```

Here is the output of a run on my machine (ThinkPad X1 Carbon with an SSD and 16G of memory). I assume in the final run everything will come from the cache, not from disk:

```
*** head -N | tail -1 ***
500000000

real    0m9,800s
user    0m7,328s
sys     0m4,081s
500000000

real    0m4,231s
user    0m5,415s
sys     0m2,789s
500000000

real    0m4,636s
user    0m5,935s
sys     0m2,684s
-------------------------

*** tail -n+N | head -1 ***

-rw-r--r-- 1 phil 9,3G Jan 19 19:49 tmp-input.txt
500000000

real    0m6,452s
user    0m3,367s
sys     0m1,498s
500000000

real    0m3,890s
user    0m2,921s
sys     0m0,952s
500000000

real    0m3,763s
user    0m3,004s
sys     0m0,760s
-------------------------

*** sed Nq;d ***

-rw-r--r-- 1 phil 9,3G Jan 19 19:50 tmp-input.txt
500000000

real    0m23,675s
user    0m21,557s
sys     0m1,523s
500000000

real    0m20,328s
user    0m18,971s
sys     0m1,308s
500000000

real    0m19,835s
user    0m18,830s
sys     0m1,004s
```

Comment: Is performance different between `head | tail` vs `tail | head`? Or does it depend on which line is being printed (beginning of file vs end of file)?

Comment: @wisbucky I have no hard figures, but one disadvantage of first using tail followed by a "head -1" is that you need to know the total length in advance. If you do not know it, you would have to count it first, which will be a loss performance-wise. Another disadvantage is that it is less intuitive to use. For instance, if you have the number 1 to 10 and you want to get the 3rd line, you would have to use "tail -8 | head -1". That is more error prone than "head -3 | tail -1".

Comment: sorry, I should have included an example to be clear. `head -5 | tail -1` vs `tail -n+5 | head -1`. Actually, I found another answer that did a test comparison and found `tail | head` to be faster. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48189289

Comment: @wisbucky Thank you for mentioning it! I did some tests and have to agree that it was always slightly faster, independent of the position of the line from what I saw. Given that, I changed my answer and also included the benchmark in case someone wants to reproduce it.

Comment: Is there a simple way to extend this solution to multiple files at once? e.g. `head -7 -q input*.txt | tail -1` to get the 7th line from several files `input*.txt`? Currently this will just obtain the 7th line from the first file listed in `input*.txt`.

Comment: What if there is no line N?

Answer (score 33):

Save two keystrokes, print Nth line without using bracket:

```
sed  -n  Np  <fileName>
      ^   ^
       \   \___ 'p' for printing
        \______ '-n' for not printing by default
```

For example, to print 100th line:

```
sed -n 100p foo.txt
```

Comment: Note that the first line has N = 1 instead of zero.

Answer (score 28):

Wow, all the possibilities!

Try this:

```
sed -n "${lineNum}p" $file
```

or one of these depending upon your version of Awk:

```
awk  -vlineNum=$lineNum 'NR == lineNum {print $0}' $file
awk -v lineNum=4 '{if (NR == lineNum) {print $0}}' $file
awk '{if (NR == lineNum) {print $0}}' lineNum=$lineNum $file
```

(*You may have to try the `nawk` or `gawk` command*).

Is there a tool that only does the print that particular line? Not one of the standard tools. However, `sed` is probably the closest and simplest to use.

Answer (score 22):

This question being tagged Bash, here's the Bash (≥4) way of doing: use `mapfile` with the `-s` (skip) and `-n` (count) option.

If you need to get the 42nd line of a file `file`:

```
mapfile -s 41 -n 1 ary < file
```

At this point, you'll have an array `ary` the fields of which containing the lines of `file` (including the trailing newline), where we have skipped the first 41 lines (`-s 41`), and stopped after reading one line (`-n 1`). So that's really the 42nd line. To print it out:

```
printf '%s' "${ary[0]}"
```

---

If you need a range of lines, say the range 42–666 (inclusive), and say you don't want to do the math yourself, and print them on stdout:

```
mapfile -s $((42-1)) -n $((666-42+1)) ary < file
printf '%s' "${ary[@]}"
```

If you need to process these lines too, it's not really convenient to store the trailing newline. In this case use the `-t` option (trim):

```
mapfile -t -s $((42-1)) -n $((666-42+1)) ary < file
# do stuff
printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]}"
```

You can have a function do that for you:

```
print_file_range() {
    # $1-$2 is the range of file $3 to be printed to stdout
    local ary
    mapfile -s $(($1-1)) -n $(($2-$1+1)) ary < "$3"
    printf '%s' "${ary[@]}"
}
```

No external commands, only Bash builtins!

Answer (score 13):

You may also used sed print and quit:

```
sed -n '10{p;q;}' file   # print line 10
```

Comment: The `-n` option disables the default action to print every line, as surely you would have found out by a quick glance at the man page.

Comment: In *GNU* `sed` all the `sed` answers are about the same speed.  Therefore (for *GNU* `sed`) this is the best `sed` answer, since it would save time for large files and small *nth line* values.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use Perl for this:

```
perl -wnl -e '$.== NUM && print && exit;' some.file
```

Comment: While testing on a file with 6,000,000 lines, and retrieving arbitrary line #2,000,000, this command was almost instantaneous and much faster than the sed answers.

Answer (score 7):

As a followup to CaffeineConnoisseur's very helpful benchmarking answer... I was curious as to how fast the 'mapfile' method was compared to others (as that wasn't tested), so I tried a quick-and-dirty speed comparison myself as I do have bash 4 handy. Threw in a test of the "tail | head" method (rather than head | tail) mentioned in one of the comments on the top answer while I was at it, as folks are singing its praises. I don't have anything nearly the size of the testfile used; the best I could find on short notice was a 14M pedigree file (long lines that are whitespace-separated, just under 12000 lines).

Short version: mapfile appears faster than the cut method, but slower than everything else, so I'd call it a dud. tail | head, OTOH, looks like it could be the fastest, although with a file this size the difference is not all that substantial compared to sed.

```
$ time head -11000 [filename] | tail -1
[output redacted]

real    0m0.117s

$ time cut -f11000 -d$'\n' [filename]
[output redacted]

real    0m1.081s

$ time awk 'NR == 11000 {print; exit}' [filename]
[output redacted]

real    0m0.058s

$ time perl -wnl -e '$.== 11000 && print && exit;' [filename]
[output redacted]

real    0m0.085s

$ time sed "11000q;d" [filename]
[output redacted]

real    0m0.031s

$ time (mapfile -s 11000 -n 1 ary < [filename]; echo ${ary[0]})
[output redacted]

real    0m0.309s

$ time tail -n+11000 [filename] | head -n1
[output redacted]

real    0m0.028s
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

The fastest solution for big files is always tail|head, provided that the two distances:

- from the start of the file to the starting line. Lets call it `S`
- the distance from the last line to the end of the file. Be it `E`

are known. Then, we could use this:

```
mycount="$E"; (( E > S )) && mycount="+$S"
howmany="$(( endline - startline + 1 ))"
tail -n "$mycount"| head -n "$howmany"
```

howmany is just the count of lines required.

Some more detail in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216614/79743

Comment: Please clarify the units of `S` and `E`, (i.e. bytes, chars, or lines).

Comment: @agc The units are lines.

Comment: i don't see how this is a good solution at all because it requires distance till end of file as an input - by the time you've calculated distance to end you've already scanned the whole file at least once, so what's the point ?

Answer (score 6):

All the above answers directly answer the question. But here's a less direct solution but a potentially more important idea, to provoke thought.

Since line lengths are arbitrary, all the bytes of the file before the nth line *need* to be read. If you have a huge file or need to repeat this task many times, and this process is time-consuming, then you should seriously think about whether you should be storing your data in a different way in the first place.

The real solution is to have an index, e.g. at the start of the file, indicating the positions where the lines begin. You could use a database format, or just add a table at the start of the file. Alternatively create a separate index file to accompany your large text file.

e.g. you might create a list of character positions for newlines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=0;print(c)}{c+=length()+1;print(c+1)}' file.txt > file.idx
```

then read with `tail`, which actually `seek`s directly to the appropriate point in the file!

e.g. to get line 1000:

```
tail -c +$(awk 'NR=1000' file.idx) file.txt | head -1
```

- This may not work with 2-byte / multibyte characters, since awk is "character-aware" but tail is not.
- I haven't tested this against a large file.
- Also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8448/30032).
- Alternatively - split your file into smaller files!

Answer (score 4):

If you got multiple lines by delimited by \n (normally new line). You can use 'cut' as well:

```
echo "$data" | cut -f2 -d$'\n'
```

You will get the 2nd line from the file. `-f3` gives you the 3rd line.

Comment: Can be also used to display multiple lines: `cat FILE | cut -f2,5 -d$'\n'` will display lines 2 and 5 of the FILE. (But it will not preserve the order.)

Answer (score 4):

Using what others mentioned, I wanted this to be a quick & dandy function in my bash shell.

Create a file: `~/.functions`

Add to it the contents:

`getline() {
  line=$1
  sed $line'q;d' $2
}`

Then add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

`source ~/.functions`

Now when you open a new bash window, you can just call the function as so:

`getline 441 myfile.txt`

Comment: There is no need to assign `$1` to another variable before using it, and you are clobbering any other global `line`.  In Bash, use `local` for function variables; but here, as stated already, probably just do `sed "$1d;q" "$2"`. (Notice also the quoting of `"$2"`.)

Comment: Correct, but it could be helpful to have self-documented code.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good answers already. I personally go with awk. For convenience, if you use bash, just add the below to your `~/.bash_profile`. And, the next time you log in (or if you source your .bash_profile after this update), you will have a new nifty "nth" function available to pipe your files through.

Execute this or put it in your ~/.bash_profile (if using bash) and reopen bash (or execute `source ~/.bach_profile`)

```sh
# print just the nth piped in line
nth () { awk -vlnum=${1} 'NR==lnum {print; exit}'; }
```

Then, to use it, simply pipe through it. E.g.,:

```
$ yes line | cat -n | nth 5
     5  line
```

Answer (score 1):

To print nth line using sed with a variable as line number:

```
a=4
sed -e $a'q:d' file
```

Here the '-e' flag is for adding script to command to be executed.

Comment: The colon is a syntax error, and should be a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431/6320039) and [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48189289/6320039) [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217130/6320039), I've implemented a tiny helper function:

```sh
function nth {
    if (( ${#} < 1 || ${#} > 2 )); then
        echo -e "usage: $0 \e[4mline\e[0m [\e[4mfile\e[0m]"
        return 1
    fi
    if (( ${#} > 1 )); then
        sed "$1q;d" $2
    else
        sed "$1q;d"
    fi
}
```

Basically you can use it in two fashions:

```sh
nth 42 myfile.txt
do_stuff | nth 42
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bash solution, but I found out that top choices didn't satisfy my needs, eg,

```
sed 'NUMq;d' file
```

was fast enough, but was hanging for hours and did not tell about any progress. I suggest compiling this cpp program and using it to find the row you want. You can compile it with `g++ main.cpp`, where main.cpp is the file with the content below. I got a.out and executed it with `./a.out`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter filename ";
    cin >> filename;

    int needed_row_number;
    cout << "Enter row number ";
    cin >> needed_row_number;

    int progress_line_count;
    cout << "Enter at which every number of rows to monitor progress ";
    cin >> progress_line_count;

    char ch;
    int row_counter = 1;
    fstream fin(filename, fstream::in);
    while (fin >> noskipws >> ch) {
        int ch_int = (int) ch;
        if (row_counter == needed_row_number) {
            cout << ch;
        }
        if (ch_int == 10) {
            if (row_counter == needed_row_number) {
                return 0;
            }
            row_counter++;
            if (row_counter % progress_line_count == 0) {
                cout << "Progress: line " << row_counter << endl;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

*gawk, sed, ruby* fastest.

*head | tail and bsd awk* slowest.

Testing on MacOS 14.1

---

Well here are few methods not otherwised mentioned here and a better benchmark to compare them.

First, let's make a 10 million line test file:

```
awk -v n=10000000 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print "Line " i}' >/tmp/tst/10m.txt
$ ls -lh 10m.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 andrew  wheel   123M Nov  3 10:50 10m.txt
% wc -l 10m.txt
10000000 10m.txt
```

Here is a Bash file with several different methods to access a single given line number:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp || exit

find_line=8999999
file="/tmp/tst/10m.txt"

case "$1" in 
    
    sed) 
        echo "sed"
        sed "${find_line}q;d" "${file}" 
    ;;
    
    ruby)
        echo "ruby"
        ruby -e "n=${find_line}.to_i" -e '$<.each_line{|line| if $.==n then puts line; exit(0) end}' "${file}"
    ;;
        
    
    perl)
        echo "perl"
        perl -e "\$n=${find_line};" -lnE 'if ($.==$n) {say $_; exit;}' "${file}" 
    ;;

    awk)
        echo "awk"
        awk -v n="${find_line}" 'FNR==n{print; exit}' "${file}"
    ;;
    
    gawk)
        echo "gawk"
        gawk -v n="${find_line}" 'FNR==n{print; exit}' "${file}"
    ;;

    head)
        echo "head"
        head -n "+${find_line}" "${file}" | tail -1
    ;;
esac
```

Now use the Perl benchmark module to print a 'pretty' comparison between them:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw(:all) ;
use Benchmark ':hireswallclock';

cmpthese(6, {
    'awk' => sub { `/tmp/tst/routines.sh awk` },
    'gawk' => sub { `/tmp/tst/routines.sh gawk` },
    'ruby' => sub { `/tmp/tst/routines.sh ruby` },
    'perl' => sub { `/tmp/tst/routines.sh perl` },
    'head' => sub { `/tmp/tst/routines.sh head` },
    'sed' => sub { `/tmp/tst/routines.sh sed` },
    });
```

Prints:

```
        Rate  awk head perl ruby  sed gawk
awk  0.342/s   -- -17% -67% -71% -72% -77%
head 0.414/s  21%   -- -60% -65% -66% -72%
perl  1.02/s 199% 147%   -- -13% -17% -31%
ruby  1.18/s 244% 184%  15%   --  -4% -20%
sed   1.23/s 260% 197%  20%   5%   -- -17%
gawk  1.48/s 332% 257%  44%  25%  20%   --
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put some of the above answers into a short bash script that you can put into a file called `get.sh` and link to `/usr/local/bin/get` (or whatever other name you prefer).

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${1}" == "" ]; then
    echo "error: blank line number";
    exit 1
fi
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
    echo "error: line number arg not a number";
    exit 1
fi
if [ "${2}" == "" ]; then
    echo "error: blank file name";
    exit 1
fi
sed "${1}q;d" $2;
exit 0
```

Ensure it's executable with

```
$ chmod +x get
```

Link it to make it available on the `PATH` with

```
$ ln -s get.sh /usr/local/bin/get
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1** : found ***much*** faster method in `awk`

- just ***5.353 secs*** to obtain a row above *`133.6 mn`* :

> ```
> rownum='133668997'; ( time ( pvE0 < ~/master_primelist_18a.txt |
>
> LC_ALL=C mawk2 -F'^$' -v \_="${rownum}" -- '!_{exit}!--_' ) )
> ```

```
in0: 5.45GiB 0:00:05 [1.02GiB/s] [1.02GiB/s] [======> ] 71%            
     ( pvE 0.1 in0 < ~/master_primelist_18a.txt | 
     LC_ALL=C mawk2 -F'^$' -v  -- ; )  5.01s user
```

`1.21s system 116% cpu` ***`5.353 total`***

```
77.37219=195591955519519519559551=0x296B0FA7D668C4A64F7F=
```

===============================================

I'd like to contest the notion that `perl` is faster than `awk` :

so while my test file isn't nearly quite as many rows, it's also twice the size, at `7.58 GB` -

I even gave `perl` some built-in advantageous - like hard-coding in the row number, and also going second, thus gaining any potential speedups from OS caching mechanism, if any

```
 f="$( grealpath -ePq  ~/master_primelist_18a.txt )"
 rownum='133668997'
 fg;fg; pv < "${f}" | gwc -lcm 
 echo; sleep 2; 
 echo; 
 ( time ( pv -i 0.1 -cN in0 < "${f}" | 
        
    LC_ALL=C mawk2 '_{exit}_=NR==+__' FS='^$' __="${rownum}" 

 ) ) | mawk 'BEGIN { print } END { print _ } NR' 
 sleep 2
 ( time ( pv -i 0.1 -cN in0 < "${f}" | 

    LC_ALL=C perl -wnl -e '$.== 133668997 && print && exit;' 

 ) ) | mawk 'BEGIN { print }  END { print _ } NR' ;

fg: no current job
fg: no current job
7.58GiB 0:00:28 [ 275MiB/s] [============>] 100%
        
148,110,134 8,134,435,629 8,134,435,629   <<<< rows, chars, and bytes 
                                               count as reported by gnu-wc



      in0: 5.45GiB 0:00:07 [ 701MiB/s] [=> ] 71%            
( pv -i 0.1 -cN in0 < "${f}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2 '_{exit}_=NR==+__' FS='^$' ; )  
   6.22s user 2.56s system 110% cpu 7.966 total
   77.37219=195591955519519519559551=0x296B0FA7D668C4A64F7F=


      in0: 5.45GiB 0:00:17 [ 328MiB/s] [=> ] 71%            
( pv -i 0.1 -cN in0 < "${f}" | LC_ALL=C perl -wnl -e ; )  
   14.22s user 3.31s system 103% cpu 17.014 total
   77.37219=195591955519519519559551=0x296B0FA7D668C4A64F7F=
```

I can re-run the test with `perl 5.36` or even `perl-6` if u think it's gonna make a difference (haven't installed either), but a gap of

***`7.966 secs (mawk2)`*** vs. ***`17.014 secs (perl 5.34)`***

between the two, with the latter more than double the prior, it seems clear which one is indeed meaningfully faster to fetch a single row way deep in `ASCII` files.

```
This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

Copyright 1987-2021, Larry Wall


mawk 1.9.9.6, 21 Aug 2016, Copyright Michael D. Brennan
```

Answer (score 0):

### To get an nth line (single line)

If you want something that you can later customize without having to deal with bash you can compile this c program and drop the binary in your custom binaries directory. This assumes that you know how to edit the .bashrc file
accordingly (only if you want to edit your path variable), If you don't know, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) is a helpful link.

To run this code use (assuming you named the binary "line").

```
line [target line] [target file]
```

example

```
line 2 somefile.txt
```

The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  if(argc != 3){
      fprintf(stderr, "line needs a line number and a file name");
      exit(0);     
  }

  int lineNumber = atoi(argv[1]); 
  int counter = 0; 
  char *fileName = argv[2];

  FILE *fileReader = fopen(fileName, "r");
  if(fileReader == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file"); 
      exit(0); 
  }

  size_t lineSize = 0;
  char* line = NULL;

  while(counter < lineNumber){
     getline(&line, &linesize, fileReader);
     counter++
  }

  getline(&line, &lineSize, fileReader);

  printf("%s\n", line);     

  fclose(fileReader); 
  return 0; 
}
```

EDIT: removed the fseek and replaced it with a while loop

Answer (score 0):

`sed '123q; d'` is ***REALLY*** slow next to `awk`, for either `BSD-sed` or `GNU-sed` :

```
  in0: 7.17GiB 0:00:15 [ 471MiB/s] [ 471MiB/s] [=====> ] 94%            
  ( pvE 0.1 in0 < ~/ABC.txt | bsd-sed '147654389q;d' ; )

 15.18s user 1.84s system 109% cpu 15.586 total
 1    900.07259=
      8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
      8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888886
      6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666
      6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666888888888
      888888888888888888888888888888888888881
    =                    
    0x10D35C8F2B57FA0034318EC78AB989C94B63BDAAB1803BE1881D435E
      604C5477626F1C07D9FDF39432A808C3C1E46D10CDC6FEB3D3B0C853
      83F2A19D1F3F2BB2E998DC1F4598A49AC74AEE73ACA279F90F52090F
      E35F2972CEFAA597F1B19774ABCA47E86893357CB4552AE38E38E38E31
    =
```

---

```
  in0: 7.17GiB 0:00:11 [ 661MiB/s] [ 661MiB/s] [=====> ] 94%            
  ( pvE 0.1 in0 < ~/ABC.txt |
                             gnu-sed '147654389q;d'; )  

 10.92s user 1.74s system 113% cpu 11.122 total
 1    900.07259=88888……
```

---

```
  in0: 7.17GiB 0:00:08 [ 858MiB/s] [ 858MiB/s] [=====> ] 94%            
  ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$___" | 
         
        mawk -v __=$__ 'BEGIN{__=+__}__<NR{exit}__==NR'; )  

 7.72s user 2.21s system 115% cpu 8.575 total

 1    900.07259=88888……
```

---

```
  in0: 7.17GiB 0:00:05 [1.22GiB/s] [1.22GiB/s] [=====> ] 94%            
  ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$___" | 

        mawk2 -v __=$__ 'BEGIN{__=+__}__<NR{exit}__==NR'; )  

 5.18s user 1.78s system 118% cpu 5.885 total
 1    900.07259=88888……
```