# SSH to server read from file

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

I want to build a small SSH manager for myself, and I want to hold all servers in a plain text file and I want to do something like:

```
ssh -i /home/edy/Documents/visually_ops.pem root@((N-th line of my file))
```

So I can use the `ssh` command and send it the N-th line of my plain text file, which is the host name. Would this be achievable?

Comment: @KerrekSB not entirely. I already knew how to extract a line from a file, but not how to use it as *part* of a command, which Stephane covered in a nice manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to print the n-th line of your host file you can use `sed`. For instance:

```
sed -n '3p' yourfile
```

will print the third line.

```
ssh -i /home/edy/Documents/visually_ops.pem root@$(sed -n '3p' yourfile)
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't really know how to append the result of this command to my `ssh` command.

Comment: Wonderful, works like a charm. You are a linux guru, my friend :)