# using head -n within if condition

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am currently trying to evaluate txt-files in a directory using bash. I want to know if the third line of the txt-file matches a certain string. The file starts with two empty lines, then the target string. I tested the following one liner:

```
if [[ $(head -n 3 a_txt_file.txt) == "target_string" ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

I can imagine that since `head -n 3` also prints out the two empty lines, I have to add them to the if condition. But `"\n\ntarget_string"` and `"\n\ntarget_string\n"` also don't work.

How would one do this correctly (And I guess it can be done more elegantly as well)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash tool to get nth line from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

Comment: `sed -n '3{p;q;}'` should give just the third line. Or use `$'\n\n'"target_string"` to embed two newlines at the start of the string.

Comment: Or also `awk 'NR==3 && /pattern/' file`. And some `exit` around to avoid keeping reading.

Comment: `\n` is two characters, not a newline, in a quoted string. `bash` does supply a non-standard quoting mechanism, `$'\n\ntarget_string'`, that may work for you though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead - it will print only the third line:

```
sed -n 3p file.txt
```

Comment: That's good, but will read all 4 GiB of a 4 GiB file. You could upgrade it to quit too: `sed -n '3{p;q;}'`, thus not reading 3.999+GiB of the 4 GiB.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to remove the top two lines:

```
head -n 3 | tail -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides sed you can try awk to print 3rd line

```
awk 'NR==3'
```

Comment: Nice, but to avoid reading the entire file I suggest `awk 'NR==3 { print; exit }'`.

Comment: I modified it to awk. Exiting immediately after 3rd line is faster, especially for big file, thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: My pleasure - I suggest you upvote my commment (hover to the left and click the up arrow - note that I will _not_ gain any reputation from this) - it'll help others spot useful information more quickly. (Apologies if you know all that already.)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `sed` instead of `head`. This gets the third line, tests if it matches, and then you can do whatever you want with it if it does match.

```
if [[ $(sed '3q;d' test_text.txt ) == "target_string" ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure `bash` solution:

```
if { read; read; read line; } < test_text.txt
   [[ $line = target_string ]]
then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi < test_text.txt
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the condition of the `if` statement can be a sequence of commands. First, read twice from the file to discard the empty lines; the third sets `line` to the 3rd line. After that, you can test it against the target string.