# How to select the nth line of a file from a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, sed, environment-variables

Possible duplicate: [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022384/1392758)

I need to select the nth line a file, this line is defined be the variable PBS_ARRAYID

The accept solution in the another question (link above) is:

```
sed 'NUMq;d' job_params
```

I'm trying to adapt for the variable like (actually I try lots of stuff, but is the one that makes more sense):

```
sed "${PBS_ARRAYID}q;d" job_params
```

But I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: invalid usage of line address 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Evidently, what you are doing wrong is trying to extract line 0 of the file. `sed` considers the first line to be line 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct:

```
sed "${PBS_ARRAYID}q;d" job_params
```

The only problem is that `sed` considers the first line to be line 1 (thanks rici), so PBS_ARRAYID must be in range [1,X], where X is the number of lines on the input file, or:

```
wc -l job_params
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` example.

Lets say we have this file:

```
cat file
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
9 nine
```

Then we have theses variable:
`var="four"`
`number=2`

Then this `awk` gives:

```
awk '$0~v {f=NR} f && f+n==NR' v="$var" n="$number" file
6 six
```

Comment: I don't understand the script, the result is not the one expected. Either way the solution of the other question absolutely works, the problem was that I starting at line zero which apparently is invalid in `sed`

Comment: If you post some data, and the expected result, it would be more easy for us to help and understand.

Comment: @rici already solve it on the comments, I was expecting an answer from him so I can accept it. There is data in the another question that I referenced, also a working solution in the question (the only problem was the parameter)