# Get the nth line from the bottom "safely"

Tags: bash, shell, head, tail

Given a file:

```
dept4.abc.edu
dept3.abc.edu
dept2.abc.edu
dept1.abc.edu
```

I know how to get the 3rd line from the bottom using the command:

```
tail -3 file | head -1
```

This is okay as long as the file length is greater or equal 3 lines `[ $(wc -l < file) -gt 3 ]`. So `tail -4 file | head -1` is still fine, but `tail -5 file | head -1` is not what I really want.

I am wondering if there is a better way and cleaner way in getting the nth line safely, by saying safely I mean if it is not there, just return me an empty string or error. Any ideas?

Comment: if you know the line number, you can use `sed 'NUMq;d' file`

Comment: ...or reverse the file using `tac` first, and then use `sed '3q;d'`

Comment: Thanks, it works! `tac file | sed '5q;d'` (given there must be an empty line in the end of the file)

Comment: @FredrikPihl why not put it in an answer :)

Comment: `awk '{x[NR]=$0} END {print x[NR-2]}' file` also works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to get the nth line from a file, see e.g. [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file?rq=1)

The simplest way to get the nth line from the bottom of the file is to use [tac](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tac-invocation.html) (inverse of `cat`) to reverse the file. Something like this:

```
tac file | sed '3q;d'
```