# How to read n-th line from a text file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, file

Say I have a text file called "demo.txt" who looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Now I want to read a certain line, say line 2, with a command which will look something like this:

```
Line2 = read 2 "demo.txt"
```

So when I'll print it:

```
echo "$Line2"
```

I'll get:

```
5 6 7 8
```

I know how to use 'sed' command in order to print a n-th line from a file, but not how to read it. I also know the 'read' command but dont know how to use it in order a certain line.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash tool to get nth line from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Using `head` and `tail`**

```
$ head -2 inputFile | tail -1
5 6 7 8
```

OR

a generalized version

```
$ line=2
$ head -"$line" input | tail -1
5 6 7 8
```

**Using sed**

```
$ sed -n '2 p' input
5 6 7 8
$  sed -n "$line p" input
5 6 7 8
```

**What it does?**

- `-n` suppresses normal printing of pattern space.
- `'2 p'` specifies the line number, `2` or (`$line` for more general), `p` commands to print the current patternspace
- `input` input file

**Edit**

To get the output to some variable use some command substitution techniques.

```
$ content=`sed -n "$line p" input`
$ echo $content
5 6 7 8
```

OR

```
$ content=$(sed -n "$line p" input)
$ echo $content
5 6 7 8
```

To obtain the output to a bash array

```
$ content= ( $(sed -n "$line p" input) )
$ echo ${content[0]}
5
$ echo ${content[1]}
6
```

**Using awk**

Perhaps an `awk` solution might look like

```
$  awk -v line=$line 'NR==line' input
5 6 7 8
```

Thanks to  Fredrik Pihl for the suggestion.

Comment: You need to get output to variable?

Comment: Only tool that is missing from your answer is `awk`, perhaps add a `awk -v line=$line 'NR==line'` for completeness.

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thanks for the suggestion. Included in the answer :)

Comment: Anyway to read it as an array like being done with 'read'? For example, I want ${line[0]}=5 and ${line[1]}=6 and so on...

Comment: @user3206874 you mean to get the output to an array for that wrap the command in `()` like `content=( $(sed -n "$line p" input) )`. Now `${content[0]}` is 5 `${content[1]}` is 6

Answer (score 0):

Perl has convenient support for this, too, and it's actually the most intuitive!

The flip-flop operator can be used with line numbers:

```bash
$ printf "0\n1\n2\n3\n4" | perl -ne 'printf if 2 .. 4'
1
2
3
```

Note that it's 1-based.

You can also mix regular expressions:

```bash
$ printf "0\n1\nfoo\n3\n4" | perl -ne 'printf if /foo/ .. -1'
foo
3
4
```

(`-1` refers to the last line)