# how can I read contents of a file and copy in a new file in Unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a text file which has 10 lines in it . I want to read contents from line 5 and save it in a new file . How can i do this in linux/unix ?

Comment: `head -5 yourfile | tail -1` or `awk 'NR==5' yourfile`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read n-th line from a text file in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056872/how-to-read-n-th-line-from-a-text-file-in-bash)

Comment: Missed the "save it in a new file" part. Just stick `> newfile` at the end of any of those commands and you are golden. `>` is "Redirect" where the stdout of the command instead of being sent to the screen for you to see is "redirected" to a file. `>>` is similar but will append to the file instead of overwriting the file. Happy Linuxing!

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve] for your next question please.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tail` command as

```
tail -n +5 yourFileName.txt > NewFile.txt
```

Here you skip first 4 lines of `yourFileName.txt` . you get the content from 5th line and save to `NewFile.txt`