# How to create PID for forked process in init script?

Tags: bash, shell, uwsgi, init, pid

I know what the problem is but I am unsure what a good solution is.

So, I have a uwsgi process that I am using for Graphite to work with Nginx. Here is some background information:

I installed uwsgi from pip and I run uwsgi with the -configfile (.ini):

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 1
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
gid = root
uid = root
chdir = /opt/graphite/conf
daemonize = /var/log/graphite/uwsgi.log
#pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi.pid
module = wsgi:application
```

I have an init script that does the following (I found it on the internet AND this is not done):

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="uwsgi daemon"
NAME=uwsgi
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
CONFIGFILE=/opt/graphite/conf/$NAME.ini
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

set -e
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

start() {
    if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ];then
       echo "${NAME} Service already running" >&2
       return 1
    fi
    echo "Starting $NAME" >&2
    $DAEMON $CONFIGFILE || echo -n "uwsgi already running"     
}

stop() {
    $DAEMON --stop $PIDFILE || echo -n "uwsgi not running"
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    echo "$DAEMON STOPPED."
}
```

Here is the situation: if I have the .ini file create the PID - it comes up with process ID that is not even close to what the actual PID is. The way it works, as from what I found is that uwsgi starts and then picks up the config file and daemonizes the process. So, if I were to use something along the lines of

```
ps -ef |awk '/[u]wsgi/{print $2}' > $PIDFILE
```

it will have 2 process IDs. e.g.

```
cat /opt/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
4121
4141
```

Now the second PID # is the actual running process.

**How can I use the awk command to grab the PID but then cut it so that I only touch the PIDFILE with the second #?**

I am not sure what command to use. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no guarantee that it will always be the second. I assume the  parent will exit and the child will persist, but it could be the other way around. Anyway,  examine the parents and then  decide which one to capture.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't searching for the right keyword or something but I found the answer here:
[How to use SED to print a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

So, what I did was added *| sed -n '2p'* to my init script and I got the script to input the correct PID into the /var/run/.pid process.

My init script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="uwsgi daemon"
NAME=uwsgi
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
CONFIGFILE=/opt/graphite/conf/$NAME.ini
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

set -e
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

start() {
    if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ];then
       echo "${NAME} Service already running" >&2
       return 1
    fi
    echo "Starting $NAME" >&2
    $DAEMON $CONFIGFILE || echo -n "uwsgi already running"
    sleep 2
    ps -ef |awk '/[u]wsgi/{print $2}'| sed -n '2p' > $PIDFILE
}

stop() {
    if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ]; then
       echo "${NAME} Service not running" >&2
       return 1
    fi
    $DAEMON --stop $PIDFILE || echo -n "uwsgi not running"
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    echo "$DAEMON STOPPED."
}

status() {
    ps aux |grep $DAEMON |sed -n '1p'
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
esac
```

Comment: This has the obvious problem that you are hard-coding the second instance, which may not always be correct. See my comment for a hopefully more robust approach.

Comment: Triplee - took me a bit to wrap my head around this but you're right and thank you for your assistance!