# How to insert text in a line that may have a special character with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I read some Q&A here about it but nothing worked for me. I understand special characters are a problem when using `sed`, but how to deal with it without know if they are present in the pattern?

In my specific case, I have a file (`file.txt`) like follows:

```
my line 1.
my line two.
...
this is [ -f another line ]
```

I am trying to insert a text (`my{Text}`) in the end of a random line.

```
MAX=$(wc -l < file.txt)
Q1=$(expr $MAX / 4)
Q3=$(( 3 * $MAX / 4 ))
LINENUMBER=$(shuf -i $Q1-$Q3 -n1)
LINE="$(head -n $LINENUMBER file.txt | tail -1)"
sed -i -e "${LINENUMBER}s~$LINE~$LINE my{Text}~g" file.txt
```

This code works well when `$LINE` is not the line that contains `this is [ -f another line ]`. In this case `$LINE my{Text}` is not replacing `$LINE`.

So how to handle with a random pattern that may need to be escaped using `sed`?

I am using GNU bash 4.3.11(1) and sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the text at the end of the line, you don't need to put the content of the existing line in your `sed` expression.  So, you could write your command as:

```
sed -i -e "${LINENUMBER}s~$~ my{Text}~" file.txt
```

which would work irrespective of whether the line being appended to has any special characters.

The whole code can be written more efficiently as:

```
max=$(wc -l < file.txt)
q1=$(( max / 4 ))
q3=$(( 3 * max / 4 ))
line=$(shuf -i $q1-$q3 -n1)
sed -i -e "${line}s~$~ my{Text}~" file.txt
```

---

See also: [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)