# How to keep certain line numbers and delete the rest

Tags: text, sed, text-processing, line-numbers

Using sed I know how to delete certain line numbers like

```
sed -i.bak -e '6d;8d;15d;' file
```

How can I achieve the reverse of it. I want to keep those lines and delete the rest. I want to do this in place, as I have huge files and I'd use this as part of a larger script. I'm still keeping a backup as I don't want to mess up my original dataset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

Comment: Specifically, the second answer contains your exact use case.

Comment: I was looking for something that does it in place. But yeah that does match to a large extent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about stopping the print for `sed` and mention wherever you want to print the lines then.

```
sed -i.bak -n '6p;8p;15p;' Input_file
```

From `man sed`:

> ```
>    -n, --quiet, --silent
>
>           suppress automatic printing of pattern space
>
>    p      Print the current pattern space.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The solution of RavinderSingh13 is nice and uses `sed` with the `-n` flag to suppress the automatic printing of the pattern space. If you do not want to use that flag, you can use a label and a sed-goto statement:

```
sed '6b;8b;15b;d;' file
```

This essentially states:

- **`6b`** If I am on line 6, branch to the end
- **`8b`** If I am on line 8, branch to the end
- **`15b`** If I am on line 15, branch to the end
- **`d`** If I did not branch yet, delete the pattern space and start the next cycle

In this case, in contrast to the usage of the `-n` flag, the pattern space is always printed at the end of the cycle.

If you want to use `awk`, you can do:

```
awk '(FNR==6) || (FNR==8) || (FNR==15)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Also :

```
sed -e '6!{8!{15!d;};}'
```

Comment: LOL _This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content._. Looks OK to me. Maybe a bit of an explanation?