# How can I output the number on the nth position in a string?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, text-manipulation

Using bash, lets say i have the following string

```
string="Same bought 5 bananas, 12 apples, 2 peaches and 16 oranges"
```

How can I trim everything except the nth number. In this case I want to output 12 which is the second number in the string.

How can I do that with bash, grep or sed?

Comment: If X is unknown, how do you establish that it's X?

Comment: @tripleee im representing the unknown with X.. X is actually an interger

Comment: What I am trying to say is that your question is unclear. What would an acceptable answer look like if we don't know what X is, or how we can find out?

Comment: Obviously if you know that X is 1, the answer is trivial; `sed 's/.*1.*/1/` but then what do you need the variable for? The result after the substitution is clearly identical to the input string, so there is no point in performing any substitution. Or are you trying to find out if the string contains 1? `case $string in *1*) echo true;; esac`

Comment: the problem is I don't want to use the character `1` since X it not always 1

Comment: You still hve not revealed how we, or you, establish the value of X. Are you simply looking for the first numeric string? `grep -Eo '[0-9]+' <<<"$string"| head -n 1` ... But you see, I have already guessed three times and each of these guesses seem plausible, yet produce wildly different results.

Comment: X is just a random number that comes with the string, but like you are saying I can probably grep only the first number on the string, thats what I'd like to be outputed

Comment: @tripleee please look at the question now and see that it has improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution Using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

> According to [Paul Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8656552/paul-hodges) and [Triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)
>   `grep -Eo '[0-9]+' <<<"$string"| sed 'nq;d'`

---

Where **n** is the position of the number

`sed 'NUMq;d'`
`NUM` is the lines to print.
`2q` says quit on the second line.
`d` will delete every other line except the last

Comment: `'2q'` says quit on the second line, but won't stop the line from being printed. `'d'` says delete every line you come to, which *does* prevent those lines from being printed. It checks them in order though, so `'2q;d'` will quit (and flush-print) on line 2 before it hits the delete, but not on line one, so the `d` prevents printing of line 1 but not line 2.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)\)\{2\}.*/\2/;/^$/d' file
```

This replaces the current line by the second occurrence of a group of numbers. The line is deleted unless a number is output.

Comment: thanks for the effort, what do you think of my own solution as well