# How to get nth line of a file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to extract from a file named `datax.txt` the second line being :

```
0/0/0/0/0/0   |   0/0/0/0/0/0   |   0/0/0/0/0/0
```

And then I want to store in 3 variables the 3 sequences `0/0/0/0/0/0`.

How am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keys is to split the problem in two:

- you want to get the nth line of a file -> see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)
- you want to split a line in chunks according to a delimiter -> that's the job of many tools, `cut` is one of them

For future questions, be sure to include a more complete dataset, here is one for now. I changed a bit the second line so that we can verify that we got the right column:

**f.txt**

```
4/4/4/4/4/4 | 4/4/4/4/4/4 | 4/4/4/4/4/4
0/0/0/0/a/0 | 0/0/0/0/b/0 | 0/0/0/0/c/0
8/8/8/8/8/8 | 8/8/8/8/8/8 | 8/8/8/8/8/8
8/8/8/8/8/8 | 8/8/8/8/8/8 | 8/8/8/8/8/8
```

Then a proper script building on the two key actions described above:

**extract.bash**

```sh
file=$1
target_line=2

# get the n-th line
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file
line=$(cat $file | head -n $target_line | tail -1)

# get the n-th field on a line, using delimiter '|'
var1=$(echo $line | cut --delimiter='|' --fields=1)
echo $var1
var2=$(echo $line | cut --delimiter='|' --fields=2)
echo $var2
var3=$(echo $line | cut --delimiter='|' --fields=3)
echo $var3
```

aaand:

```
$ ./extract.bash f.txt
0/0/0/0/a/0
0/0/0/0/b/0
0/0/0/0/c/0
```

Comment: the fact is there are more spaces : 0/0/0/0/0/0   |   0/0/0/0/0/0   |   0/0/0/0/0/0 there are 3, how do I bypass them ? otherwise, it works for the first sequence

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `there are 3` - are you telling that there is a variable number of spaces per line? 
I would suggest that you upload a snippet of your `datax.txt` file

Answer (score 3):

Read the 2nd line into variables `a`,`b` and `c`.

```
read a b c <<< $(awk -F'|' 'NR==2{print $1 $2 $3}' datax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
IFS='|' read a b c < <(sed -n 2P < datax | tr -d ' ')
```

Then the variables a, b and c are assigned to each field of the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to print a specific line of a file, so for your example on the second line:

```
sed -n -e 2p ./datax
```

Set the output of the sed to be a variable:

```
Var=$(sed -n -e 2p ./datax)
```

Then split the string into the 3 variables you need:

```
 A="$(echo $Var | cut -d'|' -f1)"
 B="$(echo $Var | cut -d'|' -f2)"
 C="$(echo $Var | cut -d'|' -f3)"
```