# How to save a specified line of a file to a variable

Tags: bash

I want to save a specified line of a file to a variable in bash script
example:

*FileToReadFromThat.txt*

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

What I want to save in a simple line:

```
variable="line 3 from $HOME/FileToReadFromThat.txt"
```

And result to get from that:

```
$ echo $varible
c
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file) in combination with [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using awk:

```
VARIABLE=`awk 'NR==3' file`
```

Or with sed

```
VARIABLE=`sed '3!d' file`
```

Comment: If your file is several GB big, you might be interested in `var=$(awk '(NR==3){print;exit}' file)`

Answer (score 1):

Or `cut`:

```sh
VARIABLE="$(<file cut -d $'\n' -f 3)"
```

Or using Bash specific `read` and the fastest for small line numbers

```sh
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ _ VARIABLE _ <file
```

or using Bash's `mapfile` and probably the most versatile and fastest way using only Bash's built-in commands without forking sub-processes:

```sh
mapfile -t -s 2 -n 1 VARIABLE <file
```