# Insert file contents at line number from bash arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have two bash arrays, one containing filenames and the other containing line numbers:

```
filepaths=(fig/par1.tex fig/par2.tex fig/par3.tex)

lines=(5 10 15)
```

I have another file (`file.tex`) into which I want to insert the contents of each file listed in `$filepaths` at the corresponding line number in `$lines$`, replacing the content of that line in `file.tex`. For example the contents of `fig/par1.tex` would replace line 5 of `file.tex` and the contents of `fig/par2.tex` would replace line 10 of `file.tex`.

I tried using a for loop, iterating over the array index:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#filepaths[@]};++i)); do
    sed -i "${lines[i]}r ${filepaths[i]}" file.tex
done
```

But I get an error for each iteration of the loop:

```
sed: 1: "file.tex": invalid command code f
```

The suggested question [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file) provides an answer to print a particular line in a file by line number. This does not answer my question, which relates to iterating over array variables to insert text at a line number.

Comment: @anubhava ideally the new text would replace line 5. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: ok it appeared your question wasn't a duplicate. I have reopened it and have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this script:

```
s=

# loop through array and build sed command
for ((i=0;i<${#lines[@]};++i)); do
   printf -v s '%s%s\n%s\n' "$s" "${lines[i]}r ${filepaths[i]}" "${lines[i]}d"
done

# check sed command    
# echo "$s"

# run a single sed
sed -i.bak "$s" file.tex
```

It is important to use an alternate delimited in `sed` i.e. `~` since your replacement string has `/` in it.

Comment: This answer inserts the _filepath_ of each file in `$filepaths` whereas I want the _contents_ of each file in `$filepaths`.