# How to convert each line to variables in CLI?

Tags: linux, variables, readline

I have a this code in my Linux server to retrieve some data from a remote URL:

```
curl domain.com/info.php > test.txt
```

The test.txt file will be like this after execution of above code:

```
customer_domain
1234
api_key
```

Now, I need to read each line of test.txt and convert each line to a separate variable in this manner:

```
var1: customer_domain
var2: 1234
var3: api_key
```

Then I will use these variables in further commands.
May you help me please how can I do this via Linux command line?

Comment: How is ssh involved here?

Comment: [use sed to get rabitrary line from file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431/12396017) like ```var2=$(sed "2q;d" test.txt) ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

Comment: @Kenster, it was my mistake. I meant linux CLI