# Error trying to read in a 2.5 gb csv file into R

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

I am trying to read in certain columns from a 2.5 gb .csv file into Rstudio using the `data.table` package and `fread` function. I am selecting the columns I need using the `select` function because without doing so I get an error message that says `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 105.7 Mb`. My input commands look like:

```
library(data.table)

setwd(<set local working directory>)

dat <- fread("File.csv", select = c(1,3,5:6,9:10,13:14,19:20))
```

When I run this code I get the following warning message telling me that `fread` stopped early `In fread("File.csv", select = c(1, 3, 5:6, 9:10, 13:14, 19:20)) :  Stopped early on line 8691`.

Is there a way to force `fread` to not stop early and to read in all rows for the selected columns?

Comment: Probably there is some irregularity on line 8691. Perhaps you can examine that line and figure out what is going on. A command line tool might be the easiest way to see that line without opening the whole file, [e.g., like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022384/903061). I'd suggest looking at the lines above and below to compare and see what's different.

Comment: What is on line 8691? One less-expensive way you can look at that row (and the one before/after is: `system("sed -ne '8690,8692p' File.csv")`. That may provide insight as to what on that row is causing problems. (Unless you have many many columns, I would not expect that row to be a demarcation between "enough memory" and "too big".)