# Fastest way to count just the first X lines of output

Tags: bash, wc

I have a large terminal output from a `tshark` filter and I want to check if the number of lines (number of pakages in this example) reaches a threshold of X.

The operation is done in a loop of many big files so I want to boost performance to the max here.

What I think to know is that `wc -l`is the fastest way to count output from a terminal command.

My line looks like this: (So tshark command does not matter here so I replaced it for readability)

```
THRESHOLD=100
[[ $(tshark -r $file -Y "tcp.stream==${streamID}" | wc -l) -gt $THRESHOLD ]] || echo "not enough"
```

While this works nearly fine I wonder if there is a way to stop after the threshold. The exact number does not matter as long as it reaches (or reaches not) the threshold.

A guess would be:

```
HEAD=$((THRESHOLD+1))
[[ $(tshark -r $file -Y "tcp.stream==${streamID}" | head -n $HEAD | wc -l) -gt $THRESHOLD ]] || echo "not enough"
```

But piping to an additional service and incrementing the threshold could be slower, isn't it?

**EDIT:** *Changing the example code to a working tshark snippet*

Comment: Have you actually tried timing it? I don't think I can simulate your platform

Comment: You are thinking correctly. Avoid spawning additional processes. Your problem is a chicked-or-the-egg problem. You have to read at least `$THRESHOLD` lines (or `EOF`) before you have a valid comparison. Since you are piping `tsharks output`, that process will complete before being passed to `wc` or `head`. Unless there are hundreds of thousands of lines+ difference between `$THRESHOLD` and the file size, I don't know you save any time between `wc` or `head`. You would just have to time a worst-case and see.

Comment: In my scenario it is hard to isolate and time just this step (requires a bit more coding) so my idea was to think about it first before start working for eventually nothing. Thanks David for the answer...

Comment: You could pipe the output of `tsharks` into a program, which not only verifies it, as you described, but then **closes its stdin**. The writer (`tsharks`) should then abort with _broken pipe_.

Comment: Sound interesting and could be exactly what I have been looking for. Could you post an example as an answer? Is there maybe a more friendly way to break the pipe :) ?

Comment: @user1934428 `head` closes stdin already.

Comment: @MichaelP Your example code looks odd. `$($(tsharks ...) | ...` executes the output (!) of `tsharks`. Did you mean `$(tsharks ... | ...` instead? Same for goes for `$(THRESHOLD+1)`. Did you mean `$((THRESHOLD+1))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Benchmark

Only one way to find out: Benchmark it yourself.
Here are some implementations that come to mind.

```
gen() { seq "$max"; }
# functions returning 0 (success) iff `gen` prints less than `$thold` lines
a() { [ "$(gen | head -n"$thold" | wc -l)" != "$thold" ]; }
b() { [ -z "$(gen | tail -n+"$thold" | head -c1)" ]; }
c() { [ "$(gen | grep -cm"$thold" ^)" != "$thold" ]; }
d() { [ "$(gen | grep -Fcm"$thold" '')" != "$thold" ]; }
e() { gen | awk "NR >= $thold{exit 1}"; }
f() { gen | awk -F^ "NR >= $thold{exit 1}"; }
g() { gen | sed -n "$thold"q1; }
h() { mapfile -n1 -s"$thold" < <(gen); [ -z "$MAPFILE" ]; }

max=1''000''000''000
for fn in {a..h}; do
  printf '%s: ' "$fn"
  for ((thold=1''000''000; thold<=max; thold*=10)); do
    printf '%.0e=%2.1fs, ' "$thold" "$({ time -p "$fn"; } 2>&1 | grep -Eom1 '[0-9.]+')"
  done
  echo
done
```

In the script from above `gen` is a placeholder for your actual command `tsharks output lines`. The functions `a` to `g` test whether `tsharks`' output has at least `$thold` lines. You can use them like

```
a && echo "tsharks printed less than $thold lines"
```

## Results

These are the results on my system:

```
a: 1e+06=0.0s, 1e+07=0.1s, 1e+08=0.8s, 1e+09=8.9s,
b: 1e+06=0.0s, 1e+07=0.1s, 1e+08=0.9s, 1e+09=8.4s,
c: 1e+06=0.0s, 1e+07=0.2s, 1e+08=1.6s, 1e+09=16.1s,
d: 1e+06=0.0s, 1e+07=0.2s, 1e+08=1.6s, 1e+09=15.7s,
e: 1e+06=0.1s, 1e+07=0.8s, 1e+08=8.2s, 1e+09=83.2s,
f: 1e+06=0.1s, 1e+07=0.8s, 1e+08=8.2s, 1e+09=84.6s,
g: 1e+06=0.0s, 1e+07=0.3s, 1e+08=3.0s, 1e+09=31.6s,
h: 1e+06=7.7s, 1e+07=90.0s, ... (manually aborted)
```

`b: ... 1e+08=0.9s ...` means that approach `b` took 0.9 seconds to find out that the output of `seq 1000000000` had at least `1e+08` (= 100'000'000) lines.

## Conclusion

From the approaches presented in this answer `b` is clearly the fastest. However, the actual results might differ from system to system (there are different implementations and versions for `head`, `grep`, ...) and for your atual use-case. I reccommend to benchmark with your actual data (that is, replace the `seq` in `gen()` with your `tsharks output lines` and set `thold` to any actually used values).

If you need an even faster approach you can experiment more with `stdbuf` and `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: Surprisingly `b` was the fastest for me too.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for sharing your results. Why were you surprised?

Comment: I think I was expecting a single process, like `awk` to win, instead of two processes `tail | head`.

Comment: On my system it is method b) too. Thanks for this nice benchmark example !

Comment: I would have expected `sed` to win here. `head` and `tail` are indeed fast ... but not that fast. I believe the sample data is also a player. What if you replace `gen` by `printf -- "x%.0s" $(seq $((max*70))) | fold -w70` and  `printf -- "x%.0s" $(seq $((max*6000))) | fold -w6000` (the latter is chosen to be bigger than `PIPE_BUF`

Comment: @kvantour I don't know and would be happy if you could test it for us :)

Comment: The reason why I expected `sed` is mainly this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022384/8344060

Comment: Good idea, albeit a bit misleading. That question seems to be about brevity not efficiency for large inputs. In the accepted answer, there is even [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file#comment34453410_6022431) pointing out that `head | tail` is faster. In that answer there is a huge discussion in the comments on why that may be.

Comment: @Socowi: surprisingly "head and tail" hands down the fastest with grep a close second. Anything else is orders of magnitude slower. I believe `sed` and `awk` are slower because they have to process and parse the _code_ per processed record. head and tail just search for newline-characters.

Comment: The combination `head` and `wc` becomes much slower when the lines are longer. Most likely because of the character counting.

Answer (score 1):

Start the `tshark` (or `tail -f -n +1 file`) with a wrapper which checks the output line count and exits after the threshold. Here is a sample in awk using `seq` to mimic the `tshark`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    cmd="seq 1 100"                        # command to execute, outputs 100 lines
    while((cmd|getline res)>0 && ++c<50);  # count to 50 lines and exit
    print res                              # test to show last line of input
    exit
}'
```

Output:

```
50
```

`seq` keeps running a while after 50, though, but quits eventually. Change `cmd="seq 1 10000000 | tee foo"` and `tail foo` I got:

```
...
11407
11408
11
```