# Bash, get array from lines of txt file without '\n' character

Tags: bash

I have a bash script and I want to create an array from the lines of a txt file without the end of line character.

The file contains countries like this (may contain spaces too).

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Antigua and Barbuda
Argentina
Armenia
Australia
Central African Republic
.
.
.
```

My goal is to have an array named `COUNTRIES` that holds every line from the text file above and to echo a string that has a couple of variables and the country in the middle without the end of line.

For example, for : `NAME = "ALEX"`,  `AGE = 21` and `COUNTRY=${COUNTRIES[2]}`, I want the command

`echo $NAME $COUNTRY $AGE` to output `ALEX Antigua and Barbuda 21` in a single line.

I tried using `mapfile COUNTRIES < ${COUNTRIES_FILE}`, but the above echo outputs `21ALEX Antigua and Barbuda` for some reason.

Using `mapfile -t COUNTRIES < ${COUNTRIES_FILE}` outputs the same string.

I then tried `COUNTRIES+=($(cat ${COUNTRIES_FILE}))`, but that did not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022441/11261546) answer your question?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/SRjAgQ showing your code (with `mapfile -t`) working fine as-is -- no extra newlines added. (And note that variable names should be _lowercase_ to avoid conflicting with [reserved names used by the shell itself](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html); see the line from that specification: "*The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications*").

Comment: are you sure you are setting variables like that? `NAME = "ALEX"`? there should not be any whitespaces around `=`

Comment: Your file has CRLF line breaks. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: *facepalm*, I confused which sample was actual vs expected output. @Barmar is completely right above, and that makes this a duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)