# Adding the 3rd line of every txt file into a new txt file

Tags: bash

I have a dataset with subjects of which the SUVr is calculated and put on the 3rd line of a txtfile, specific to each subject (so every subject has a different txtfile containing the SUVr).
My question is: How can I get the 3rd line (which is the SUVr value) of every subjects' txtfile and place them in a new txtfile, so all the SUVRs of every subject are placed in one txtfile? I'm using the Linux terminal to do this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Use ```grep``` for that lines you wanna ```>>``` to a file. No example provided - No exact answer possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
for file in $(find . -type f); do sed '3q;d' $file; done > output.txt
```

Some explanation about the command parts:

- `find . -type f`: list all files

  - If you need to filter by extension: `find . -type f -name "*.txt"`
- `sed '3q;d' filename`: prints the 3rd line of the file

  - See more: [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)
- `> output.txt`: write to `output.txt` (use `>>` if you want to append)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` works well for this also.

```
awk '3 == FNR { print $0; }' /path/to/$files.* >found
```

FNR is File Number of Records, so it grabs the 3rd line from each file without executing over and over, or needing a `find`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

```
sed -n 3p -s *.txt > output.txt
```