# Line output with awk

Tags: awk

There is a command and its output:

```
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | head -2 | sort -r

root         1  0.0  0.0    904   520 ?        Sl   12:09   0:00 /init
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

How to print only the first line with awk? or only second lane like this:

```
root         1  0.0  0.0    904   520 ?        Sl   12:09   0:00 /init
```

or this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash tool to get nth line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | awk 'NR==1'

ps aux --sort=-%cpu | awk 'NR==2'
```

No need for `head` or `sort`.