# displaying a specific line from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a script that displays the third line of a file, for example, filename.txt using only grep, without using backticks, &&, || or ; or sed and awk in only one line.

So I have tried this command: `grep -w "3" filename.txt` but it doesn't seem to work, any rectifications?

Comment: You're not searching for a pattern ..  That's what `grep` is for.  I don't understand the reluctance to use `cat` or `head` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need grep since you aren't searching for a pattern, you want line #3 (or line *N*).

To get line 3 you can output the first 3 lines from the file, then take the last line from those three:
`head -3 filename.txt | tail -1`

You mention backticks, so if you want to assign that, or output it, enclose it in `$(...)` instead of backticks.
`linethree=$(head -3 filename.txt | tail -1)`

If the file is very large and the line *N* you want is far into the file it would be more efficient to use sed, such as
`sed 4321q;d filename.txt` or
`sed <n>q;d filename.txt`
as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431/17300).

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer .. Grep is not intended to be used in the way OP is asking.

Comment: It is more appropriate to do this with `sed` or `awk`, but the OP wants only `grep`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin - the OP wants line N and thought grep was the way to get it. As an [XYProblem](https://xyproblem.info/) X is "I want line #3" and Y is "how do I get line 3 from grep" having assumed the solution is grep.

Comment: There is no disagreement about `grep` being a wrong tool for this task. A single call to `sed` or `awk` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH version 4 or higher `mapfile`:

Use `mapfile` to read third line only `-s 2` discards 2 lines and `-n 1` copies only 1 line into array named `third_line`:

```
mapfile -s 2 -n 1 third_line < filename.txt
```

Output array contents:

```
printf "%s" "${third_line[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -n` to number the lines, then you can pipe the output to another grep to extract the third line:

```
grep -n ^ file | grep ^3:
```

If you need to remove the `3:` from the beginning of the line, you can pipe it to

```
| cut -f2- -d:
```

or, if you insist on `grep`, you can use

```
| grep -Po '(?<=^3:).*'
```

i.e. only output the part preceded by `3:` at the beginning of a line (but `-P` is not supported everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

If `tail` is allowed:

```
grep --after-context=2 -m 1 -e ".*$" filename.txt | tail -n1
```