# How can I make my Slurm script loop over a list of file names?

Tags: python, shell, slurm

I have a slurm script to run my python code:

```
#!/bin/bash -l                                                                                                    
#SBATCH --nodes=1                                                                                                 
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                                                                                                
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1                                                                                         
#SBATCH --mem=10G                                                                                                 
#SBATCH --account=my_account                                                                                 
#SBATCH --qos=default                                                                                           
#SBATCH --time=2-00:00:00                                                                                         
###Array setup here                                                                                               
#SBATCH --array=1                                                                                                 
#SBATCH --open-mode=truncate                                                                                      
#SBATCH --output=out_files/output.o                                                                              

module purge
module load my_cluster
module load Miniconda3/4.9.2

eval "$(${EBROOTMINICONDA3}/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"

conda activate my_conda_env

cd /my_directory

python my_python_code.py -filename file_a.txt
```

This works, but at the moment, it just launches 1 job and uses `file_a.txt` as an argument.

How can I launch 10 simultaneous jobs? I know I can use:

```
#SBATCH --array=1-10
```

but I want to use `file_a.txt` as the argument for job 1, `file_b.txt` as the argument for job 2 etc..

I would like to provide the lists of file names as a separate text file if possible, which is read by the slurm script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html), the `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` environment variable will be set to the (1-indexed) task ID. We can use this env var with `sed` to get the Nth line from a list of files

**my_files.txt**

```
file_a.txt
file_b.txt
file_c.txt
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022441/3324095) for the `sed -n "xp"` command.

**my_slurm_job.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l                                                                                                    
#SBATCH --nodes=1                                                                                                 
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                                                                                                
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1                                                                                         
#SBATCH --mem=10G                                                                                                 
#SBATCH --account=my_account                                                                                 
#SBATCH --qos=default                                                                                           
#SBATCH --time=2-00:00:00                                                                                         
###Array setup here                                                                                               
#SBATCH --array=1                                                                                                 
#SBATCH --open-mode=truncate                                                                                      
#SBATCH --output=out_files/%a_output.o                                                                              

module purge
module load my_cluster
module load Miniconda3/4.9.2

eval "$(${EBROOTMINICONDA3}/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"

conda activate my_conda_env

cd /my_directory

# Get the Nth line from my_files.txt
file_name=$(sed -n "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p" < my_files.txt)

python my_python_code.py -filename ${file_name}
```

**Edited** to add the Task ID to the output file name as per FlyingTeller's comment and the Slurm [docs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html#file_names).

Comment: :-) feel free to improve the answer if I've missed anything out.

Comment: Might add that it can be a good idea to add `%a` to the output file , so `#SBATCH --output=out_files/output.%a.o` which creates one output file per array task

Comment: Thanks! So firstly, I think I need to add a space after `file_name=` otherwise I get an error message about `-n: command not found`. But then if I have a space I don't think anything is assigned to `file_name`.

Comment: I believe it was missing `$(...)` around the sed part - I edited the answer and it works now, thank you!